# Query runs duration: fast / fetch: slow, but GROUP BY (or any aggregate function) makes it duration: slow / fetch: fast

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, duration

I have a table `process_execution_data` (29,4mi rows) that consists of

```
 id    | key_name   | value      | piid       | created     | modified    | process_id
-------+------------+------------+------------+-------------+-------------+-----------
 <int> | <varchar>  | <longtext> | <varchar>  | <datetime>  | <datetime>  | <int(11)>
```

Basically, this table holds the `key, value` pairs of existing variables during a execution `piid` of a process `process_id`

There lots of indexes (singulars and composites), pretty much all columns and composition-of-columns are covered.

An "average" `process \ piid` has roughly 60~ disctinct `key_name`.

For this specific database/table, there are roughly 30~ different `process_id`

```
SELECT
  p.name as process_name,
  ped.value as fw_spaceleft_disk_C
FROM process_execution_data ped
INNER JOIN process p ON ped.process_id = p.id -- This table 'process' is just a {id:name} table, 30~ rows
WHERE
  ped.key_name = 'fw_disk_space_left_c'
```

This query runs (Duration: 0.375s, Fetch: ~40s) and returns 238k rows.

If I add a `GROUP BY ped.process_id` it now returns the expected 30 rows, but takes (Duration: 50s, Fetch: 0.000s)

`EXPLAIN SELECT` with the `GROUP BY`.

```
id | select_type | table | partitions | type       | possible_keys | key           | key_len | ref               | rows  | filtered | Extra
---+-------------+-------+------------+------------+---------------+---------------+---------+-------------------+-------+----------+----------------------------------------------
1  | SIMPLE      | p     |            | index      | id_name,id    | id_name       | 519     |                   | 66    | 100.00   | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1  | SIMPLE      | ped   |            | ref        | (5 indexes)** | processid_key | 519     | brain.p.id,const  | 31    | 100.00   |
```

**all,key_piid_modified_created,processid_key,processid,key

My current understanding is that `Duration` is the time it takes for the database/engine to process the query and collect the beginning of results, whereas `Fetch` is how long it takes to completely send?/transfer? all the rows of data.

Therefore, if I have a fast Duration but long Fetch query it means that the query is optimized/fast but the data is too large and if it gets solved somehow (ie: by reducing the amount of rows of data), it should be Duration: fast and Fetch: fast and then problem solved.

I quite do not understand how the engine is able to process a query that results into 283k rows of data in blazingly fast 0.375s but when it is told to `GROUP BY` it takes 20x that time to "simply" group results.

---

Questions:

a) Is my understanding of Duration/Fetch wrong?

b) Is it 'normal' for a extremely fast Duration (0.375s) query to become slow (Duration 50s) because of a GROUP BY?

c) Is there anything that can be optimized? Feels like 40s~50s (sum of Duration/Fetch, for either query) is longer than it should.

---

Additional data as requested by Rick James

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE `process_execution_data`
>>>
 CREATE TABLE `process_execution_data` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `key_name` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
   `value` longtext,
   `piid` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
   `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
   `modified` datetime DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `process_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
   `flags` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `all` (`process_id`,`key_name`,`modified`,`created`),
   KEY `key_piid_modified_created` (`key_name`,`piid`,`modified`,`created`),
   KEY `processid_key` (`process_id`,`key_name`),
   KEY `processid` (`process_id`),
   KEY `key` (`key_name`),
   KEY `piid` (`piid`),
   KEY `created` (`created`),
   KEY `modified` (`modified`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=31134333 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

SHOW CREATE TABLE `process`
>>>
 CREATE TABLE `process` (
   `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `name` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
   `status` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
   `description` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
   `bpm` varchar(512) DEFAULT NULL,
   KEY `id_name` (`id`,`name`),
   KEY `id` (`id`),
   KEY `name` (`name`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=261 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

and

```
EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT
  p.name as process_name,
  ped.value as fw_spaceleft_disk_C
FROM process_execution_data ped
INNER JOIN process p ON ped.process_id = p.id -- This table 'process' is just a {id:name} table, 30~ rows
WHERE
  ped.key_name = 'fw_disk_space_left_c'
>>>

'{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "2.42"
    },
    "nested_loop": [
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "ped",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "all",
            "key_piid_modified_created",
            "processid_key",
            "processid",
            "key"
          ],
          "key": "key_piid_modified_created",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "key"
          ],
          "key_length": "514",
          "ref": [
            "const"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "1.00",
            "eval_cost": "0.20",
            "prefix_cost": "1.20",
            "data_read_per_join": "2K"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "key",
            "value",
            "process_id"
          ],
          "attached_condition": "(`brain`.`ped`.`process_id` is not null)"
        }
      },
      {
        "table": {
          "table_name": "p",
          "access_type": "ref",
          "possible_keys": [
            "id_name",
            "id"
          ],
          "key": "id_name",
          "used_key_parts": [
            "id"
          ],
          "key_length": "4",
          "ref": [
            "brain.ped.process_id"
          ],
          "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
          "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
          "filtered": "100.00",
          "using_index": true,
          "cost_info": {
            "read_cost": "1.00",
            "eval_cost": "0.22",
            "prefix_cost": "2.42",
            "data_read_per_join": "2K"
          },
          "used_columns": [
            "id",
            "name"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}'




EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT
  p.name as process_name,
  ped.value as fw_spaceleft_disk_C
FROM process_execution_data ped
INNER JOIN process p ON ped.process_id = p.id -- This table 'process' is just a {id:name} table, 30~ rows
WHERE
  ped.key_name = 'fw_disk_space_left_c'
GROUP BY ped.process_id
>>>

'{
  "query_block": {
    "select_id": 1,
    "cost_info": {
      "query_cost": "2.42"
    },
    "grouping_operation": {
      "using_temporary_table": true,
      "using_filesort": true,
      "nested_loop": [
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "ped",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "all",
              "key_piid_modified_created",
              "processid_key",
              "processid",
              "key"
            ],
            "key": "key_piid_modified_created",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "key"
            ],
            "key_length": "514",
            "ref": [
              "const"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "index_condition": "(`brain`.`ped`.`key` <=> ''fw_disk_space_left_c'')",
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "1.00",
              "eval_cost": "0.20",
              "prefix_cost": "1.20",
              "data_read_per_join": "2K"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "id",
              "key",
              "value",
              "process_id"
            ],
            "attached_condition": "(`brain`.`ped`.`process_id` is not null)"
          }
        },
        {
          "table": {
            "table_name": "p",
            "access_type": "ref",
            "possible_keys": [
              "id_name",
              "id"
            ],
            "key": "id_name",
            "used_key_parts": [
              "id"
            ],
            "key_length": "4",
            "ref": [
              "brain.ped.process_id"
            ],
            "rows_examined_per_scan": 1,
            "rows_produced_per_join": 1,
            "filtered": "100.00",
            "using_index": true,
            "cost_info": {
              "read_cost": "1.00",
              "eval_cost": "0.22",
              "prefix_cost": "2.42",
              "data_read_per_join": "2K"
            },
            "used_columns": [
              "id",
              "name"
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}'
```

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for both tables, plus `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...` both with and without the `GROUP BY`.  There will be more details in the JSON, possibly enough to answer your question.  (Meanwhile, I am puzzled by the `EXPLAIN` that you did provide; it seems wrong.)

Comment: OP message has been edited to provide the requested additional data.

Answer (score 0):

In `process`, I would change

```
KEY `id_name` (`id`,`name`),
KEY `id`      (`id`),
```

to

```
PRIMARY KEY(id)
```

unless you have some reason not to.

Meanwhile, `ped` needs

```
INDEX(key_name, process_id,  value)
```

and I would drop these

```
KEY `processid_key` (`process_id`,`key_name`),
KEY `processid`     (`process_id`),
```

as being redundant with `all`.

The column order in an `INDEX` is important.  More discussion:  [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)

**Duration/Fetch**

Those are cryptic terms used by Explain.  I look only at the total time.  They *may* be saying that the `GROUP BY` has to generate a temp table and that messes with their timers.

Comment: Hi Rick. Thanks for your quick response. I've forwarded your input to the responsible team. We are cloning our prod db to a new dev environment so we can "mess" with it and see if it brings any better results. It will take +1~2d then I shall have more news.